# Protection levels and survival analysis of machinery?

Tags: bayesian, logistic, optimization, survival

I'm familiar with the basics of survival analysis; we use the cumulative distribution to ask, "What's the probability of a machine still being operable after X days of usage?" Eventually, the probability will asymptotically shrink to 0.

Let's say I need for 5 fully functioning washing machines at my laundry mat. For the moment, let's ignore the time component. Let's just assume that any given washing machine has a 50% probability of being fully operational. In this case, I would need a protection level of 10 washing machines, at minimum, to ensure that (on average) 5 are at all times operational.

I need to take this idea but reintroduce the time component: Let's say I have the main room where 5 washing machines are staged for customer use, but I also have a repair room where X brand new washing machines are ready replacements should any given unit break down due to exhaustion. My question is- **How would I incorporate survival analysis (age of washing machine(s)) into a model, which informs me how many replacement washing machines, X, I should have on hand?**

For context, I prefer probabilistic programming via PyMC3. In my problem, censorship is an issue where washing machines could be removed for various reasons other than failure due to age (ie grafiti, resale, or any arbitrary reason.) So, I'm curious, how would a Bayesian model this problem?

My gut instinct is simply to take the survival analysis outputs for each unit in use, say ages in years `[1, 3, 2, 5]` and survivability `[0.8, 0.5, 0.75, 0.2]` and sum them together, which returns 2.5, meaning 2.5 units are likely to remain functional. And to ensure that my 5 threshold is met, I need 3 more units in the repair room. This assumes that the survivability of an never-used washing machine is 100%, which could be unsubstantiated. So I might need a random effects model to account for age of units in the categories, in-use and never-used.

Now, things could get even more complicated if we introduce a supply chain time element as well. It could take simply 1-week for a unit to be delivered, which might be negligible. Or, it could take 12-15 weeks for a unit to be delivered. In this case, I might need for the survivability of unit in use with the expected delivery timeline of a replacement unit in mind. But I have no idea how to incorporate this information into a model.

**Is there a name for this sort of modeling besides survival analysis?**

Answer (score -1):

The US National Institute of Standards and Technology has a helpful introduction to many of these issues under the title [Assessing Product Reliability](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/apr.htm). Although that might be considered a type of survival analysis, there are considerations not typical of clinical survival analysis--like distinguishing between "non-repairable" and "repairable" systems and modeling "repairable" systems--in ways that are related to your question.

Putting that into a broader context, as in your last paragraph, involves additional disciplines. [Supply-chain modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_chain) is a major field itself. Search on that term. You might find further information under the more generic term [operations research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research). These latter disciplines are well outside my expertise.